# Is there a possibility to control the RGB LED using makecode.calliope.cc?

Tags: calliope

There seems to be no corresponding element in the graphical language provided by makecode (its possible using lab.open-roberta.org editor). I didn't find anything in the Javascript section either.

Does somebody know a workaround (like accessing the RGB LED on a lower level)?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the first tab "Basic" and then choose "set led to $color".
Obviously irritating that that code block is not subsumed beneath the "LED" tab.